# ggplot2 (scatter plot and several fitted values) in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

How I can modify the following code to have a plot between x and y (scatter plot) and the fitted values X0.025 and y=X0.975 as the curves (lines) on the plot.  (please run `plot(m6)` to see the plot which I am looking for to make by `ggplot`)

```
library(quantregGrowth)
data(growthData)
m6<-gcrq(y~ps(x, lambda=seq(0,100,l=20)), tau=c(0.025,0.975), n.boot=10, 
data=growthData) 
plot(m6)
```

I tried to make this plot by ggplot and here is the code:

```
 library(ggplot2)
    library(plotly)
    temp <- data.frame(m6$fitted)
    growthData_b <- cbind(growthData, temp)

    a <- ggplot(data=growthData_b, aes(x, y=X0.025)) + geom_line() + 
    geom_line(data=growthData_b, aes(x, y=X0.975), color = "red")  + theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
ggplot(data=growthData_b, aes(x, y=X0.025)) + 
geom_line() + 
geom_line(data=growthData_b, aes(x, y=X0.975), color = "red", linetype = 2)  + 
theme_bw() + 
geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y), shape = 1)
```

Comment: @ MLavoie, thanks so much, also any idea regarding how i can bring the points into the plot when we use plot_ly() %>% add_lines(data = growthData_b, x = ~x, y = ~X0.025) %>% add_lines(data = growthData_b, x = ~x, y = ~X0.975)

Comment: just a question, when you work with Plotly, how you share it with other people? I made an account but it seems that the software shares the plot to public.

Comment: you can save it as an html page. look at the htmlwidgets package.